# Cannot open Nvidia Visualizer Profiler(NVVP)

Tags: nvidia, 22.04

I get the following error after trying to open NVVP

An error has occurred. See the log file
/home/somthing/.eclipse/org.eclipse.platform_4.4.1_1396419852_linux_gtk_x86_64/configuration/1686769093693.log.

which is the following:
https://dl.orangedox.com/Qz4ihx
tried to paste the log here but was detected as spam so use the link to see it please.

I installed latest eclipse version, did not fix it.
What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by following these steps:

1. Install `openjdk-8-jdk`:

   ```
   sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk
   ```
2. Run:

   ```
   nvvp -vm /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java
   ```

Also check this link: https://mrprajesh.blogspot.com/2020/02/resolved-cannot-launch-nvidia-visual.html